# hadoop -D property=value, how to pass empty string to value

Tags: hadoop

how to pass empty string to value?

`-D <property=value>            use value for given property`

I use **hadoop pipes**

I tried

```
-D prop1=
-D prop2=value2
```

but it doesn't work

```
# HadoopPipes::JobConf
# jobconf.hasKey(prop1) is false
```

Comment: What about quotes "" ? `-D prop1=""`

Comment: Why do you want to pass empty string?

Comment: @RashadIbrahimov jobconf.get("prop1") is `"`